# Why is the background color of an `image` element on a page spans over the whole `div` it is in?

Tags: html, css, next.js, flexbox, tailwind-css

I would like to control the height of the image via CSS and in the meantime, I do not want to color the whole `div` the image is in only the `image`.

```html
<div class="flex flex-col bg-blue-200 items-center">
  <div class="flex h-24">
    <img class="bg-red-300 object-contain" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex mt-12">
    <img class="bg-red-300 object-contain" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mnygoet7/47/

[image]

Comment: i mean you can control the hieght using `.bg-red-300.object-contain{
  height: 200px;
}`  im sure u know this aswell, your question doesnt seem very clear, and i dont understand what you mean by `I do not want to color the whole div the image is in only the image`

Comment: @Zyfella I define the `bg-red-300` at the image not at the `div`, still the whole `div` is colored. This is the main problem.
The second image acting like I want to, but there I do not control the height of the image with `h-24`.

(Sorry for being unclear)

Comment: I keep reading this and it just seems like ure using the wrong classes, `` .h-24 { height: 6rem; } `` so maybe just use a different class  ?? and your placeholder cannot have a backround if it covers everything, it self is gray and has no room in the div to have a background color of red. and when you say the whole div is colored, what div ? the main div ? the picture also has `200/200 `, see https://jsfiddle.net/fn8r7k2q/41/

Comment: do you think you can draw what your elements should look like ? then i have a better view, sry but my brain is smkoing im so confused :D

Comment: you know that u will never see this background-color behind an image except u dont display it?

Comment: Yeah, I know it, this is just a demonstration.
The real problem comes form the `next/image` component and its `blur` placeholder. Basically the placeholder spans across the whole `div` (like the red background here), while it should only appear behind the image while the real image is not loaded.
I just tried to simplify the problem

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution

move the `h-24` class to the `img` rather than having in `div`

##### Problem

The problem you are facing is because you are saying the div to have `h-24` and `flex`, flex will fill the available space, and then inside `img` you are using `object-contain` which will shrink proportionally. So the img is taking the entire space but scales the image proportionally in the given `height` so the background is visible.

##### Output

[image]

##### Code

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center bg-blue-200">
  <div class="flex">
    <img class="h-24 bg-red-300 object-contain" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
  </div>
  <div class="mt-12 flex">
    <img class="bg-red-300 object-contain" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```